# how to make linkLabel acting as simple hyper link on right click in .net winforms

Tags: .net, winforms, linklabel

are there any ways to make linkLabel (.net 4.0) working as simple hyperlink on right mouse click - i mean to open a menu with "open in new tab", "open in new window" and so on.

if not, is there any way to develop custom control that will act like this?

actually i just need to be able to encapsulate simple hyperlink in some kind of control.

Comment: Why don't you just set its ContextMenuStrip property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On mouse down event for your link label, when you identify that its right mouse button, Open up a context menu and show up the options you wish to show.

```
private void OnMyLinkLableMouseDownEvent(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        //Show menu with required options
    }
}
```

If you plan to use this at multiple places in your application, then create a derived type from link label and add this event handler to it

Thanks to [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant): you can also use ContextMenu(or ContextMenuStrip property not sure which one)  if menu options are never going to change for different instances of LinkLabel.